# If $ \textbf{Pr}(A|B) = 1 $ and $ \textbf{Pr}(B|A) = 0 $, then is it true that $ \textbf{Pr}(B) < 0.5 $?

Tags: probability

I am looking for a convincing explanation for

> $ \textbf{Pr}(A|B) = 1 $ and $ \textbf{Pr}(B|A) = 0 $ imply $ \textbf{Pr}(B) < 0.5 $.

Is this true? If so, then under what circumstances? If not, then why?

Thanks.

Comment: Hi Ali. Don’t forget to accept the post that you think best answers your question by clicking on the check mark beside that post. This is basic etiquette to be observed here at Mathematics Stack Exchange. Not only do you award points to the owner of the post for his/her efforts, you also award yourself $ 2 $ points.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By definition,
$$  P(A \mid B) P(B) = P(A \cap B) = P(B \mid A) P(A). $$
Then inserting the values given,
$$ P(B) = 1 \cdot P(B) = P(A \cap B) = 0 \cdot P(A) = 0, $$
which means you can avoid division by zero, but still conclude that $P(B)=0$.

Answer (score 1):

Its true. $P(A\mid B) = 1 \Rightarrow P(A\cap B)/P(B) = 1\Rightarrow P(B) = P(A\cap B)$, and $P(B\mid A) = 0 \Rightarrow P(B\cap A)/P(A) = 0 \Rightarrow P(B\cap A) = 0 \Rightarrow P(A\cap B) = 0 \Rightarrow P(B) = P(A\cap B) = 0 < 1/2$

Comment: But conditional probability is not defined as P(B)=0. This solution says 0/0 =1

Comment: This is the sort of thing that can be used to prove $1=0$.

Comment: But still we cannot use $P(A|B)=P(A∩B)/P(B)$ formula as $P(B)=0$

Comment: I suppose one could argue that this shows that it is not possible that $P(A|B)=1$ and $P(B|A)=0$ simultaneously. Therefore the original implication is vacuously true.

Comment: @Rahul You definitely CAN have $P(A|B)=1$ and $P(B|A)=0$ at the same time. For instance, picking a number uniformly on $[0,1]$. Let $B$ be the event that you pick $\frac{1}{2}$ and $A$ be the event that you pick any number on $[0,1]$.

Comment: @avid19 This explanation is convincing enough I think. Thanks.